# RDFlib adding blank nodes in triples

Tags: rdf, rdflib, blank-nodes

I'm using the RDFlib to automate the process of creating the DSD.
I want to get a format as follows:

```
_:refPeriodStep1 a qb4o:HierarchyStep;
etc...
```

but using this:

```
graph.add((BNode('refPeriodStep1'), RDF.type, URIRef(qb4o + 'HierarchyStep')))
```

the file is not created as desired.

I tried to use the function n3():

```
graph.add((BNode('refPeriodStep1').n3(), RDF.type, URIRef(qb4o + 'HierarchyStep')))
```

but I get the following error:

```
AssertionError: Subject _:refPeriodStep1 must be an rdflib term
```

Is there any way to get it as wanted?

Comment: What do you mean by "is not created as desired"?

Comment: @StanislavKralin in that way a [ ] is created, instead I want to obtain _:refPeriodStep1. Do you have any idea?

Comment: If preserving blank node labels matters, use URIs instead.

Comment: @StanislavKralin using URIs like this: g.add((URIRef('_', 'refPeriodStep1'), RDF.type, URIRef(qb4o + 'HierarchyStep'))), I get this: <_refPeriodStep1> a qb4o:HierarchyStep .

Comment: Am I using URIRef incorrectly?

Comment: yes, you are ... a URI is **not** a blank node. You have to use a proper URI in it's form an it defintely does never start with a `_` - that is a blank node. Anyways, what Stanislav was suggesting is that if you want to be able to identify the blank node later on by it's name, why not using a URI then? I mean, that's the whole purpose of a URI,  Uniform Resource **Identifier**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested in comment, if the name of the blank node matter, you should probably use an URI instead.
Your last comment suggest you are not using URIRef correctly when stating `URIRef('_', 'refPeriodStep1')` (according to my understanding).

If you want your `refPeriodStep1` to not be a blank node while keeping it (somehow) unprefixed, you can define an empty prefix using the `namespace_manager` of your graph.

For example the following code is creating a `refPeriodStep` of type `qb4o:HierarchyStep` using `Namespace` fonctionnalities instead of URIRef directly (this is probably the easiest way to do if you reuse a lot your namespaces as stated here [in the documentation](https://rdflib.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro_to_creating_rdf.html)) :

```py
from rdflib.namespace import NamespaceManager
from rdflib import BNode, Namespace, Graph

QB4O = Namespace('http://example.com/qb4o#')
n = Namespace('http://example.com/base-ns#')

g = Graph()
g.namespace_manager = NamespaceManager(Graph())
g.namespace_manager.bind('qb4o', QB4O)
g.namespace_manager.bind('', n)

g.add((n['refPeriodStep1'], RDF.type, QB4O['HierarchyStep']))

g.serialize('test.ttl', format='turtle')
```

This will output the following (in turtle) which is close to what you expect :

```
@prefix : <http://example.com/base-ns#> .
@prefix qb4o: <http://example.com/qb4o#> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix xml: <http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace> .
@prefix xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .

:refPeriodStep1 a qb4o:HierarchyStep .
```

Note that if you try to serialize a blank node in `n-triples` format, RDFLib will keep the name used when creating that blank node, such as :

```
_:refPeriodStep1 <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://example.com/qb4o#HierarchyStep> .
```